# call template inside template

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml file:

```
<root>
  <directors>
    <director>
      <name></name>
      <country></country>
    </director>
    (...)
    <director>
      <name></name>
      <country></country>
    </director>
  </directors>
  <movies>
    <movie>
      <country><country>
    </movie>
    (...)
    <movie>
      <country></country>
    </movie>
  </movies>
</root>
```

In my XSL transformation I want to create XML file with the`movie` and `director` elements grouped by country. I have managed to extract every distinct country:

```
    <xsl:template name="countries"> 
      <xsl:for-each 
        select="distinct-values(/root/directors/director/country | /root/movies/movie/country)">
        <xsl:element name="country">
          <xsl:element name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </<xsl:template>
```

And what I want to do now is to create elements `<movies>` and `<directors>` inside `<country>` containing elements that have child elements matching parent country:

```
<country>
  <name>UK</name>
  <movies> [movies having element country="UK"] </movies>
  <directors> [as above] </directors>
</country>
```

I was trying to call template with current country name as a parameter inside template, but it doesn't work.

```
    <xsl:template name="countries"> 
      <xsl:for-each 
        select="distinct-values(/root/directors/director/country | /root/movies/movie/country)">
        <xsl:element name="country">
          <xsl:element name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:element name="movies">
            <xsl:call-template name="movie">
              <xsl:with-param name="country" />
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </<xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="movie">
      <xsl:param name="country" />
      <xsl:for-each select="/root/movies/movie">
        <xsl:if test="country=$country">
          <!--TODO-->
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

Looking at the complexity level of my "solution" I am assuming that I am trying to do it the wrong way. How to get elements that have `<country>` element specified by iteration of `for-each` loop? I want to do it separately for movies and directors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling templates with params, you can group using `xsl:for-each-group`. (I figured if `distinct-values()` is working for you, you must be using XSLT 2.0.)

**XML Input** (with some values added for testing)

```
<root>
    <directors>
        <director>
            <name>Mr. A</name>
            <country>UK</country>
        </director>
        <director>
            <name>Mrs. B</name>
            <country>US</country>
        </director>
    </directors>
    <movies>
        <movie>
            <country>US</country>
        </movie>
        <movie>
            <country>UK</country>
        </movie>
    </movies>
</root>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*/director|*/movie" group-by="country">
        <country>
          <name><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></name>
          <directors>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[self::director]"/>
          </directors>
          <movies>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[self::movie]"/>
          </movies>
        </country>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<root>
   <country>
      <name>UK</name>
      <directors>
         <director>
            <name>Mr. A</name>
            <country>UK</country>
         </director>
      </directors>
      <movies>
         <movie>
            <country>UK</country>
         </movie>
      </movies>
   </country>
   <country>
      <name>US</name>
      <directors>
         <director>
            <name>Mrs. B</name>
            <country>US</country>
         </director>
      </directors>
      <movies>
         <movie>
            <country>US</country>
         </movie>
      </movies>
   </country>
</root>
```

## [<kbd>Working Example</kbd>](http://xsltransform.net/pPzifpF)

This should be easy to extend. For example, if you wanted to remove the `country` elements from `director` and `movie`, you'd just need to add a single template (`<xsl:template match="country"/>`).

Answer (score 1):

At least, you need to assign value to the template parameter :

```
<xsl:call-template name="movie">
    <xsl:with-param name="country" select="." />
</xsl:call-template>
```

Alternatively, you can use XPath predicate expression to get `movie` elements where `country` child equals to the `country` of current `xsl:for-each` iteration :

```
<!-- inside foreach 'distinct country' loop -->
<xsl:element name="movies">
    <xsl:for-each select="/root/movies/movie[country=.]">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:element>

.....
.....

<xsl:template match="movie">
    <!--TODO-->
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a pure XSLT 1.0 solution** (also runs correctly with XSLT 2.0 processors), **which is so far the shortest**. It also is as efficient as an XSLT 2.0 solution using `<xsl:for-each-group>`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:key name="kCountryByVal" match="country" use="."/>
  <xsl:key name="kDirMovieByCountry" match="director|movie" use="concat(country, name())"/>

  <xsl:template match="country[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kCountryByVal',.)[1])]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <name><xsl:value-of select="."/></name>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kDirMovieByCountry',concat(.,'director'))[1]
                            | key('kDirMovieByCountry',concat(.,'movie'))[1]" mode="do"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="director|movie" mode="do">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}s">
      <xsl:copy-of select="key('kDirMovieByCountry',concat(country,name()))"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Do note another achievement**: if a country doesn't have any directors, or any movies, no empty `<directors/>` or `<movies/>` element is generated.

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<root>
    <directors>
        <director>
            <name>James Cameron</name>
            <country>CA</country>
        </director>
        <director>
            <name>Steven Spielberg</name>
            <country>US</country>
        </director>
    </directors>
    <movies>
        <movie>
            <name>Titanic</name>
            <country>US</country>
        </movie>
        <movie>
            <name>E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial</name>
            <country>US</country>
        </movie>
    </movies>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<country>
   <name>CA</name>
   <directors>
      <director>
         <name>James Cameron</name>
         <country>CA</country>
      </director>
   </directors>
</country>
<country>
   <name>US</name>
   <directors>
      <director>
         <name>Steven Spielberg</name>
         <country>US</country>
      </director>
   </directors>
   <movies>
      <movie>
         <name>Titanic</name>
         <country>US</country>
      </movie>
      <movie>
         <name>E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial</name>
         <country>US</country>
      </movie>
   </movies>
</country>
```

**Key concepts**:

1. **[Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**
2. *Composite* **[keys](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#key)** with *union* **[pattern](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#patterns)**
3. XSLT processing model, **[templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#rules)**, **[built-in templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule)**, **[modes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#modes)**
4. `<xsl:apply-templates>` instruction, "*push*-style", *polymorphism*, avoiding `<xsl:call-templates>`
5. **[AVT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)** in an `xsl:element`